# When R.H.S have negative int and unsigned int outside the range of int in arithmetic operation

Tags: c, unsigned-integer, integer-arithmetic

I apologize for the title since I had to somehow find a unique one.

Consider the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int b = 2147483648; // To show the maximum value of int type here is 2147483647
  printf("%d\n",b);

  unsigned int a = 2147483650;
  unsigned int c = a+(-1);
  printf("%u\n",c);
}
```

The output of the above program when run on a 64 bit OS with gcc compiler is:

```
-2147483648
 2147483649
```

Please see my understanding of the case:

Unsigned int a is outside the range of signed int type. In the R.H.S (-1) will converted to unsigned int since the operands are of different types. The result of converting -1 to unsigned int is:

```
-1 + (unsigned int MAX_UINT +1) = unsigned int MAX_UINT = 4294967295.
```

Now R.H.S will be:

```
unsigned int MAX_UINT + 2147483650
```

Now this looks like it is outside the range of unsigned int. I do not know how to proceed from here and it looks like even if I proceed with this explanation I will not reach the empirical output.

Please give a proper explanation.

PS: To know how `int b = 2147483648` became `-2147483648` is not my intention. I just added that line in the code so it is pretty clear that `2147483650`
is outside the range of `int`.

Comment: `2147483648` is not the maximum value of `int` type - it cannot be represented by an `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I know it's not. I used this value to show that 2147483650 is outside the range of int.

Comment: You are asking for undefined behaviour to be explained. `2147483648` cannot be respresented by a `int` which is why `INT_MIN` is defined as `(-2147483647 - 1)` and not `-2147483648`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I am not asking the behaviour of 2147483648. I want to know how the we get the result of the variable c as 2147483649.

Answer (score 3):

`2147483648` is not a 32-bit `int`, it is just above `INT_MAX` whose value is `2147483647` on such platforms.

`int b = 2147483648;` is implementation defined. On your platform, it seems to perform 32-bit wrap around, which is typical of two's complement architectures but not guaranteed by the C Standard.

As a consequence `printf("%d\n", b);` outputs `-2147483648`.

The rest of the code is perfectly defined on 32-bit systems, and the output `2147483649` is correct and expected. The fact that the OS by *64 bit* plays a very subtle role in the evaluation steps but is mostly irrelevant to the actual result, which is fully defined by the C Standard.

Here are steps:

- `unsigned int a = 2147483650;` no surprise here, `a` is an `unsigned int` and its initializer is either an `int`, a `long int` or a `long long int` depending on which of these types has at least 32 value bits. On Windows and 32-bit linux, it would be `long long int` whereas on 64-bit linux it would be `long int`. The value is truncated to 32-bit upon storing to the `unsigned int` variable.

  You can verify these steps by adding this code:

  ```
  printf("sizeof(2147483650) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(2147483650));
  printf("         sizeof(a) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(a));
  ```
- The second definition `unsigned int c = a+(-1);` undergoes the same steps:

  - `c` is defined as an `unsigned int` and its initializer is truncated to 32 bits when stored into `c`. The initializer is an addition:
  - the first term is an `unsigned int` with value `2147483650U`.
  - the second term is a parenthesized expression with the unary negation of an `int` with value `1`. Hence it is an `int` with value `-1` as you correctly analyzed.
  - the second term is converted to `unsigned int`: conversion is performed modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, hence the value is `4294967295U`.
  - the addition is then performed using unsigned arithmetics, which is specified as taking place modulo the width of the `unsigned int` type, hence the result is an `unsigned int` with value `2147483649U`, (`6442450945` modulo 2<sup>32</sup>)
  - This `unsigned int` value is stored into `c` and prints correctly with `printf("%u\n", c);` as `2147483649`.

If the expression had been instead `2147483650 + (-1)`, the computation would have taken place in 64 bits signed arithmetics, with type `long int` or `long long int` depending on the architecture, with a result of `2147483649`. This value would then be truncated to 32-bits when stored into `c`, hence the same value for `c` as `2147483649`.

Note that the above steps do not depend on the actual representation of negative values. They are fully defined for all architectures, only the width of type `int` matters.

You can verify these steps with extra code. Here is a complete instrumented program to illustrate these steps:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("\n");
    printf("             sizeof(int) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(int));
    printf("    sizeof(unsigned int) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(unsigned int));
    printf("        sizeof(long int) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(long int));
    printf("   sizeof(long long int) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(long long int));
    printf("\n");

    int b = 2147483647; // To show the maximum value of int type here is 2147483647
    printf("                   int b =  2147483647;\n");
    printf("                       b -> %d\n",b);
    printf("               sizeof(b) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(b));
    printf("      sizeof(2147483647) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(2147483647));
    printf("      sizeof(2147483648) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(2147483648));
    printf("     sizeof(2147483648U) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(2147483648U));
    printf("\n");

    unsigned int a = 2147483650;
    printf("          unsigned int a =  2147483650;\n");
    printf("                       a -> %u\n", a);
    printf("     sizeof(2147483650U) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(2147483650U));
    printf("      sizeof(2147483650) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(2147483650));
    printf("\n");

    unsigned int c = a+(-1);
    printf("          unsigned int c =  a+(-1);\n");
    printf("                       c -> %u\n", c);
    printf("               sizeof(c) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(c));
    printf("                  a+(-1) -> %u\n", a+(-1));
    printf("          sizeof(a+(-1)) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(a+(-1)));
#if LONG_MAX == 2147483647
    printf("         2147483650+(-1) -> %lld\n", 2147483650+(-1));
#else
    printf("         2147483650+(-1) -> %ld\n", 2147483650+(-1));
#endif
    printf(" sizeof(2147483650+(-1)) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(2147483650+(-1)));
    printf("        2147483650U+(-1) -> %u\n", 2147483650U+(-1));
    printf("sizeof(2147483650U+(-1)) -> %d\n", (int)sizeof(2147483650U+(-1)));
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
             sizeof(int) -> 4
    sizeof(unsigned int) -> 4
        sizeof(long int) -> 8
   sizeof(long long int) -> 8

                   int b =  2147483647;
                       b -> 2147483647
               sizeof(b) -> 4
      sizeof(2147483647) -> 4
      sizeof(2147483648) -> 8
     sizeof(2147483648U) -> 4

          unsigned int a =  2147483650;
                       a -> 2147483650
     sizeof(2147483650U) -> 4
      sizeof(2147483650) -> 8

          unsigned int c =  a+(-1);
                       c -> 2147483649
               sizeof(c) -> 4
                  a+(-1) -> 2147483649
          sizeof(a+(-1)) -> 4
         2147483650+(-1) -> 2147483649
 sizeof(2147483650+(-1)) -> 8
        2147483650U+(-1) -> 2147483649
sizeof(2147483650U+(-1)) -> 4
```

Comment: How is the second part pretty straight forward? Please explain how -1 is converted to unsigned int.

Comment: Im getting there, an expanded answer is being written

Comment: Thanks. This helped. So in nutshell when unsigned arithmetic overflows then module addition is done and hence the result.

Comment: @Fawaz.A.R: unsigned arithmetic actually never overflows because it is defined as modular arithmetics. All operations are performed modulo 2^32.

Comment: What about signed arithmetic ?

Answer (score 1):

```
int b = 2147483648;
printf("%d\n",b);
// -2147483648
```

**Conversion** of an integer (any signed or unsigned) that is outside the range of the target *signed* type:

> ... either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. C11 §6.3.1.3 3

In your case with the signed integer 2147483648, the implementation-defined behavior appears to map the lowest 32-bits of the source `2147483648` to your `int`'s 32-bits.  This may not be the result with another compiler.

---

`a+(-1)` is the same as `a + (-(1u))` same as `a + (-1u + UINT_MAX + 1u)` same as `a + UINT_MAX`.  The *addition*   overflows the `unsigned` range, yet *unsigned* overflow wraps around.  So the sum is `2147483649` *before* the assignment.  With the below code, there is no out of range conversion.  The only conversion is `signed 1` to `unsigned 1` and `long 2147483650` (or `long long 2147483650`) to `unsigned 2147483650`.  Both in range conversions.

```
unsigned int a = 2147483650;
unsigned int c = a+(-1);
printf("%u\n",c);
//  2147483649
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at it like this

```
 2147483650  0x80000002
+        -1 +0xFFFFFFFF
 ----------  ----------
 2147483649  0x80000001
```

Where does the `0xFFFFFFFF` come from? Well, `0` is `0x00000000`, and if you subtract `1` from that you get `0xFFFFFFFF` because unsigned arithmetic is well-defined to "wrap".

Or taking your decimal version further, `0 - 1` is `UINT_MAX` because `unsigned int` wraps, and so does the sum.

```
your value      2147483650
UINT_MAX      + 4294967295
                ----------
                6442450945
modulo 2^32   % 4294967296
                ----------
                2147483649
```